# how to change color of popup window in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In image
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZFJM.png there is pop-up window. 
My question is how to change background color of that pop-up window also how to change foreground text color of that pop-up window. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You have to change the default **Ambiance** theme settings file. Check this [link](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/12/04/eclipse-papercut-10-eclipse-on-ubuntu-fixing-the-black-background-color-in-hover/).

Comment: Does it answers your question